# UITableView, how do I know what Section during cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a UITableView displaying a list of Cities.
I want to separate them by State.  I can't seem to figure out how to get it to pick the right items out of my Array.
If Section 1 (Arizona) has 2 Cities and Section 2 (California) has 2 Cities, during cellForRowAtIndexPath, Section 2, City 1 has an index of 0, even though it's the 3rd item in my array.
I thought about just turning my City Array into a State Array, where each item holds an Array of Cities, but I still don't know what section I'm on and therefore don't know which City Array under the States Array I would need to access.

Comment: Alright...apparently I failed to properly research this one.  Sorry about the dumb question.

Comment: A little dumb, perhaps; but not extremely: I had a similar question when I first started doing iPhone dev.

Comment: The reason you probably failed to solve this yourself is that the row and section properties are UIKit additions to NSIndexPath. If you look up the NSIndexPath documention, they are not documented. They are however documented here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. I had the same question and went looking in the wrong direction (UITableView).

Comment: This is NOT a dumb question. I've very glad you asked, saved me time looking at other crappy sources.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The method is called

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The indexpath parameter contains a row and section property.

```
indexPath.section  
indexPath.row
```

Here's documentation link for the [NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsindexpath) class.

Answer (score 11):

you can use `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row`

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3, 4 and 4.2

> Using Switch

```
switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            print("Write your code for section number one.")
        case 1:
            print("Write you code for section number two")
        default:
            return
        }
```

> Using if else

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
            print("Write your code for section number one.")
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            print("Write your code for section number two.")
        }
```